# Air conditioner

Tags: insulation

I removed two old wall air conditioners from our house. Unfortunately they do not make these wall units the small anymore and having a Hard time finding a small air conditioner? I was wondering does anybody have any advice? This wall unit would have to be 12.5 inches in height by 20 width. The other unit was 12height by 18.5 width. Thank you!

Comment: Where have you looked? A quick browse thru Walmart shows a couple of options which look like they'll fit. Remember than a narrower unit would typically have some sort of sliding or expanding accordion spacers on the sides which would allow it fit fit into a larger hole.

Comment: @brhans keep in mind a wall unit and a window unit are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just plug the hole in the wall (or greatly reduce it to fit the pipes needed, but it is probably not in a good location for the smaller hole needed) and purchase a mini-split heat pump. If in a cold region, consider a mini-split heat pump with extended cold range heating operation. Happily, those tend to have good cooling efficiency as well.

That's the "modern, better" verson of a "through the wall air conditioner" where the parts are completely separated rather than being built like a longer window unit.

Window units (if you find one to fit) are not generally a good choice for a through the wall application, as they are not set up for the longer area where there's no ventilation in the through-wall sleeve, as they expect to be in a much thinner window sash.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. These are smaller room spaces that would only need a 5000 BCU. I am currently looking into units that could go into the wall and unfortunately I’m not having any luck finding small wall units. Due to the cost of split units I am Trying to look into other alternatives.